# Remove extra scrolling from a html template

Tags: html, github-pages

I am trying to use this html theme in github pages: 
http://themes.typebold.com/veil/thumbnail-gallery.html
But when you use the scrollbar the images move after you are done scrolling.
This makes it impossible to click on the images when on a tablet or a phone, so I'd like to remove the option all together.
The full gitub repository is here:
https://github.com/syunghong/veil
I'm pretty new at html, so im not sure what I need to edit in order to remove it.
Hope someone can help me out.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by your Javascript. 
You can stop the plugin from loading by removing the attribute `data-parallax` from your HTML

Comment: So I kept only thumbnail-gallery.html from the repository and just renamed it to index.html so that github pages could use it. From what I can see there is no remaining data-paralax in the thumbnail-gallery.html file?

Comment: whoops, do you mean: <ul class="gallery-v3 offset-top05 swipe-gallery" data-parallax='{"y": -100}'>  ?

Comment: Yep change `<ul class="gallery-v3 offset-top05 swipe-gallery" data-parallax='{"y": -100}'>` to `<ul class="gallery-v3 offset-top05 swipe-gallery">`